# Is there a boolean method to know whether `gameEngine` is paused or not in Flutter Flame?

Tags: flutter, flame

I would like to check if gameEngine is paused in if statement, but it seems there is no such method.

```
if (isGameEnginePaused) {
   //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are within a `FlameGame` instance you can simply check the `paused` flag.

```dart
class YourGame extends FlameGame {
  ...
  if(paused) {
    // whatever you want to do
  }
}
```

Do note that the `update`-loop won't be running when the game is paused, so you can't do the check within an `update` method.

To check from outside of the game you can just use:

```dart
if(game.paused) {
  // whatever you want to do
}
```